# why won't select2 events fire correctly?

Tags: jquery-select2

Given the below coffeescript

```
class ModalController
  constructor: (modalClass) ->
    @modalClass = modalClass
    @enableSelect2()
    @clearSelectOptions()

  enableSelect2: () ->
    $('.select2-init').select2()
      .on 'select2-open', (e) ->
        console.log e
      .on 'select2:selecting', (e) =>
        console.log 'added'
        @validatePresenceOf($(e.target))
```

I would expect that when I've made a selection the above code specifically the line calling `.on 'select2:selecting` should fire, this is def not the case as is documented in the below snippet.

[image: https://cl.ly/image/2P3d3F0y3k1o/Screen%20Recording%202015-04-03%20at%2010.38%20AM.gif]

I'm basing my understanding of this off the select2 docs

[image: https://cl.ly/image/2Z3k0q2b2H1V/Image%202015-04-03%20at%2010.40.37%20AM.png]

How to resolve this?

re possible typo in event selection,

the below coffeescript

```
  enableSelect2: () ->
    $('.select2-init').select2()
      .on 'change', (event) =>
        if event.added
          @validatePresenceOf($(event.target))
      .on 'select2:selecting', (e) =>
        console.log "selecting"
      .on 'select2:select', (e) =>
        console.log "select"
      .on 'select2-removed', (e) =>
        @validatePresenceOf($(e.target))
```

produces the below, notice no log statements (though i've hacked the validations i'm looking for by the use of the `event.added` check.

[image: https://cl.ly/image/1l3Y3h1a1e2t/Image%202015-04-03%20at%2011.05.41%20AM.png]

the pattern `select2:eventname` doesn't do anything, ie, no logging, no hooks.  this is odd.  I found the `select2-eventname` pattern on a random site I found on the internet.  This is super odd and disconcerting for me, this seems like a straightforward bit of code.

Comment: that's so weird. Can you try to replicate it on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: You are using a mix of Select2 3 and 4 events, what version are you actually using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *appear* to be using Select2 3.x, but you are referencing things from the Select2 4.0.0 documentation.

Select2 4.0.0 documentation: https://select2.github.io/
Select2 3.5.2 documentation: http://select2.github.io/select2/

There is also a link on the homepage that links to the Select2 3.5.2 documentation.

---

You are using `select2-open` which appears to be working and is a 3.5.2 event, but you are also trying to use `select2:selecting`, which is a 4.0.0 event. The Select2 3.5.2 event for `select2:selecting` is `select2-selecting` (notice the `-` instead of a `:`).

Other notable changes when looking at the event documentation

- `change` used to contain `added` and `removed` properties, for checking when things were added and removed. Now you should use the `select2:select` event for checking when things are added, and `select2:unselect` for when things are removed.
- `select2-selecting` is now `select2:selecting`
- `select2-removing` is now `select2:unselecting`
- `select2-removed` is now `select2:unselect`
- `select2-opening` is now `select2:opening`
- `select2-open` is now `select2:open`

Answer (score 0):

Possible typo. Should that be

.on 'select2-selecting' ...

instead of

.on 'select2:selecting' ...

Comment: yeah, i've tried that and for some reason no hooks with that pattern are being picked up.  very strange.  i added context to the question to illustrate that.